# data.table ordering gives unexpected results inconsistent with base R

Tags: r, data.table

I have noticed some odd behaviour with `data.table`. It seems to involve the use of backticks (**`**). I have prepared a simple example here:

```r
library(data.table)

data.table(v1 = c("2", "1", "10"))[order(v1)]
#>    v1
#> 1:  1
#> 2: 10
#> 3:  2

data.table(v1 = c("`2`", "`1`", "`10`"))[order(v1)]
#>      v1
#> 1: `10`
#> 2:  `1`
#> 3:  `2`

c("2", "1", "10")[order(c("2", "1", "10"))]
#> [1] "1"  "10" "2"

c("`2`", "`1`", "`10`")[order(c("`2`", "`1`", "`10`"))]
#> [1] "`1`"  "`10`" "`2`"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As you can see, using backticks changes the order of rows. Whereas base R doesn't show this behaviour (gives the expected result).

Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a difference between `base::order` and `data.table::order`. The manuals for `?data.table::order`, says they are different.

> Using C-locale makes the behaviour of sorting in data.table more consistent across sessions and locales. The behaviour of base::order depends on assumptions about the locale of the R session.

```
data.table(v1 = c("`2`", "`1`", "`10`"))[ order(v1) ]
#      v1
# 1: `10`
# 2:  `1`
# 3:  `2`

data.table(v1 = c("`2`", "`1`", "`10`"))[ base::order(v1) ]
#      v1
# 1:  `1`
# 2: `10`
# 3:  `2`
```

Comment: .. and the way to get them to be the same is to use `base::order(v1, method="radix")`, for which the sort order does not depend on locale.

Comment: @r2evans which is very nicely explained in your answer in the linked post.

Comment: and I added the dependence on locale to _that_ answer :-)